# how join 2 columns and extract year and count postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, count

I have this table

[image]

I need to know the most popular color every year

I just know how to join this table with this code, I don't know how to extract the year and count the color

```
select FS.order_date, FS.quantity, DP.color
from fact_sales FS
join dim_product DP
on FS.product_id = DP.product_id
```

and give me the example result

```
order_date  quantity    color 
2016-01-07  2           Silver 
2016-02-07  2           Black
2016-02-07  1           Silver 
2017-05-07  1           Black 
2017-05-07  4           Red 
2017-06-07  2           Black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count the total quantity by year and then pare down to one year.  The first part is:

```
select date_trunc('year', FS.order_date) as yyyy, DP.color, sum(FS.quantity) as quantity
from fact_sales FS join
     dim_product DP
     on FS.product_id = DP.product_id
group by yyyy, color;
```

For the second part, you can use a Postgres extension, `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (date_trunc('year', FS.order_date)), date_trunc('year', FS.order_date) as yyyy, DP.color, sum(FS.quantity) as quantity
from fact_sales FS join
     dim_product DP
     on FS.product_id = DP.product_id
group by yyyy, color
order by yyyy, quantity desc;
```